# SharePoint 2013 Email Enable Library Search Index with html tables from SalesForce

Tags: search, email-enabled-library

I am currently indexing a library that receives emails from SalesForce. Inside these emails they contain html tables that pertain certain information that I was hoping to index without requiring me to do anything fancy to the files/data incoming into the library.

Does anyone know how to make these emailed items with the html table to be searched? I want the end users to be able to find the context inside of the html tables. I know that the emails are showing up in the search however, the contents of the tables is not searchable.

Also, wondering if a quick workaround would be to strip the email header from the files? Would this help?